# How to set breakpoint in Delphi JVCL units?

Tags: delphi, debugging, delphi-2010, breakpoints, jvcl

I'm debugging a **Delphi** code that use TJvProgramVersionCheck component from the excellent **JVCL** libs.

So I'd like to **put a breakpoint somewhere in JvProgramVersionCheck unit** but it doesn't work. The breakpoint icon show a cross - not active !

I tried to put a breakpoint when calling the TJvProgramVersionCheck method, do a debug "Step into" and of course, it doesn't break !

Back to the JVCL installation, I re-installed with 'Compile debug units' option ON, added debug DCU's inside Debug LIB path ... but still don't work.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the JVCL source path to the project's debug source path (Project Options | Debugger | Source Path)

Comment: and if i remember well, you must set the projects options at Compiler tab to use debugging DCU

best regards,
Radu

Comment: It works with the "use debugging DCU" option enabled. Ouch ! Thank you, I can now debug at will !

Answer (score 1):

You must add JVCL and JCL *.PAS units (not the DCU's) to the library paths.